# Nextjs 'next build' Error occurred prerendering page

Tags: typescript, next.js

Error occurred prerendering page "/500". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

Error occurred prerendering page "/404". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

Error occurred prerendering page "/". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

```
Build error occurred
    Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /
        /_error: /404
        /_error: /500
        /categories/list
        /colors/list
```

'categories/list.tsx' code

```
import Link from "next/link";
import { ReactElement } from "react";
import Layout from "../../components/layout";

export default function Categories() {
    return (
        <>
        <h1>Categories</h1>
        <h2>
            <Link href="/">
                <a>Back to home</a>
            </Link>
        </h2>
        </>
    )
}

Categories.getLayout = function getLayout(page: ReactElement) {
    return (
      <Layout>
        {page}
      </Layout>
    )
  }
```

I tried to build next.js app for production.
but, run 'next build', occurred error.

how to solve that?

---

_app.tsx

```
import type { ReactElement, ReactNode } from 'react'

import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { NextPage } from 'next'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import store from '../app/store'

type NextPageWithLayout = NextPage & {
  getLayout?: (page: ReactElement) => ReactNode
}

type AppPropsWithLayout = AppProps & {
  Component: NextPageWithLayout
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppPropsWithLayout) {
  // Use the layout defined at the page level, if available
  const getLayout = Component.getLayout ?? ((page) => page)

  return getLayout(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

[pages folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KPYO.png)

Comment: Can you show your _app.tsx file and pages folder

Comment: @TusharShahi Yes! upload my pages folder

Comment: Pls share _app.tsx too

Comment: @TusharShahi Add _app.tsx

Comment: It looks exactly like the recommended method from the docs. I hope the provider is working fine.

Comment: Try moving the `getLayout` call inside the `Provider`, i.e. `<Provider store={store}>{getLayout(<Component {...pageProps} />)}</Provider>`.